# counting the lines and extract the floating point values and compute the average of the values

Tags: python

So i need to write a program that prompts for a file name, then opens that file and reads through the file, looking for lines of the form:X-DSPAM-Confidence: 0.8475
I am stuck in getting the sum of the extracted values and counting the lines and printing to show the user.

```
out_number = 'X-DSPAM-Confidence: 0.8475'
Num = 0.0
flag = 0
fileList = list()

fname = input('Enter the file name')
try:
    fhand = open(fname)
except:
    print('file cannot be opened:',fname)

for line in fhand:
    fileList = line.split()
    print(fileList)
    for line in fileList:

if flag == 0:
    pos = out_number.find(':')
    Num = out_number[pos + 2:]
    print (float(Num))
```

Comment: Not sure if this is just a cut and paste error but there's nothing inside your for loop 'for line in fileList'

Answer (score 0):

You have an example line in your code, and when you look through each line in your file, you compute the number in your example line, not in the line from the file.

So, here's what I would do:

```
import os
import sys

fname = input('Enter the file name: ')
if not os.path.isfile(fname):
    print('file cannot be opened:', fname)
    sys.exit(1)

prefix = 'X-DSPAM-Confidence: '
numbers = []
with open(fname) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if not line.startswith(prefix): continue
        num = float(line.split(":",1)[1])
        print("found:", num)
        numbers.append(num)
    # now, `numbers` contains all the floating point numbers from the file
average = sum(numbers)/len(numbers)
```

But we can make it more efficient:

```
import os
import sys

fname = input('Enter the file name: ')
if not os.path.isfile(fname):
    print('file cannot be opened:', fname)
    sys.exit(1)

prefix = 'X-DSPAM-Confidence: '
tot = 0
count = 0

with open(fname) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if not line.startswith(prefix): continue
        num = line.split(":",1)[1]
        tot += num
        count += 1
print("The average is:", tot/count)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("X-DSPAM-Confidence:\s(\d+.\d+)")
sum = 0.0
count = 0
fPath = input("file path: ")
with open('fPath', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        match = pattern.match(line)
        if match is not None:
             lineValue = match.group(1)
             sum += float(lineValue)
             count += 1
print ("The average is:", sum /count)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
count=0
x=0
for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:") : continue
    x=float(line.split(":")[1].rstrip())+x
    count=count+1
    
    
output=x/count
print("Average spam confidence:",output)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.